# How to get all last rows at second level in MultiIndex DataFrame whose second level has variable length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'thread_id': [0,0,1,1,1,2,2],
    'message_id_in_thread': [0,1,0,1,2,0,1],
    'text': ['txt0', 'txt1', 'txt2', 'txt3', 'txt4', 'txt5', 'txt6']
}).set_index(['thread_id', 'message_id_in_thread'])
```

[image]

And I want to keep all the last second level rows, meaning that:

- For `thread_id==0` I want to keep the row `message_id_in_thread==1`
- For `thread_id==1` I want to keep the row `message_id_in_thread==2`
- For `thread_id==2` I want to keep the row `message_id_in_thread==1`

This can easily be achieved by doing df.iterrows(), but I would like to know if there is any direct indexing method.

I look for something like `df.loc[(:, -1)]`, which selects from all (`:`) level 1 groups, the last (`-1`) row of that block/group, but obviously this does not work.

Comment: hmmm. looks like you can groupby on the thread_id and select the last row with `.last`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need both levels use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).tail(1)
print (df)
                                text
thread_id message_id_in_thread      
0         1                     txt1
1         2                     txt4
2         1                     txt6
```

If need only first level use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).last()
#df = df.groupby(level=0).nth(-1)
print (df)
           text
thread_id      
0          txt1
1          txt4
2          txt6
```